# This occurred when runing Telethon: Getting difference for channel updates xxxxxxxxxx caused TimeOutError

Tags: telethon

Full error message is
`Getting difference for channel updates xxxxxxxxxx caused TimeOutError; ending getting difference prematurely until server issues are resolved`

I think it was because of the network status. After I restart the program, everything is fine.

So how do I restart to get difference without restarting the whole program? How do I handle this error?

Comment: This is not an error. It's a warning. Telegram was having server-side issues and the library was unable to get updates. Once Telegram is back up, the library should detect the missed updates and retry.